# Removing digits from beginning of filename

Tags: find, rename, parameter

I was hoping this would work:

```
$ find . -type f -exec basename {} \; | while EFS= read -r f; do echo "${f##[0-9]}"; done
```

But, for example, for files named as:

> 1foo
>   11bar

it returns:

> foo
>   1bar

when

> foo
>   bar

is expected.

PS: ultimately, I want to `mv "$f"` to the modified name (and also do other modifications)

EDIT:

PS2: it's not a duplicate if you consider PS. Anyways, the answer marked check satisfies me.

Comment: The title says "beginning of file" but your code is gathering file*names* and then renaming them. Also, unsetting "EFS" appears to be a typo for unsetting "IFS"

Comment: Your solution necessitates to know in advance the number of digits. Is there not a more general way? Why doesn't `##` take care of it in the parameter expansion?

Comment: Yes, I meant filename, sorry.

Comment: Do you care how it's done? Do you have a "rename" utility installed?

Comment: I was using EFS, and replacing it by IFS works the same. I'd like to understand why my solution doesn't work, but I'll accept rename as well (it is installed)

Comment: @NasirRiley: that's NOT AT ALL how ranges in shell patterns (aka globs) work. Erwann: `##pattern` removes the longest prefix match for the pattern, but `[0-9]` is a pattern that matches _only_ one character. Also, unsetting IFS only matters here if it is already set nonstandardly (unlikely since you don't know what it is) or any of your filenames contains leading or trailing spaces or tabs (pretty unusual).

Comment: @dave_thompson_085 That is how they work. The pattern should be `[0-9][-09]` if he wants to match two digits and `[0-9][0-9][0-9]` for three and so on and so forth. I've tested it and the code works when the ranges are specified in the way that I just stated. When run in the way that he has it, it only removes one digit. The issue with my previous comment is that I just made a small mistake which I've just cleared up.

Comment: @NasirRiley: yes those patterns (except you made one typo) work for fixed lengths of 2 or 3 digits, but `[0-999]` does not work for variable lengths from 1 to 3 which is what you previously said and I objected to. (OP seems to need 1 and 2, but not 3.)

Comment: @dave_thompson_085 And it is for that reason that I deleted the comment and posted the new one. `[0-9]` as many times as it's needed (depending on the number of digits that need to be replaced) is the better way to do it.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`find . -type f -exec basename {} \; | while IFS= read -r f; do echo "${f##+([0-9])}"; done` should provide the desired results.

This uses extended pattern matching operators, of which `+()` means match one or more.

Additional information can be found in the Pattern Matching section of the bash man page.

Comment: You need to enable the `extglob` option to make this work.

Answer (score 5):

If `rename` (sometimes called `prename`) is an option:

```
find . -name '[[:digit:]]*' -type f -exec rename 's:^(.*/)\d+([^/]*)\z:\1\2:s' {} +
```

explanation:

- `( )` patterns in parentheses are saved and can be recalled by the number of appearance
- `.*/` the directory portion must be preserved
- `([^/]*)\z`: all non-/ characters till the end of the subject.
- `\1\2` reprint the captured directory and everything past the digits in the output name

You can use the `-n` option in `rename` to do a dry-run for checking the results first.

Comment: That won't work. The file names seen by `rename` start with `./`, not digits. If you replace `-exec` with `-execdir`, with some `find` implementations including GNU `find`, that will still be `./`.

Comment: @StéphaneChazelas good point - updated.